# How to specify filter in Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: graph, sdk

I am trying the following:

```
GraphServiceClient? _userClient;

...

_userClient.Sites.GetAsync(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.QueryParameters.Filter = "displayName eq 'sms'";
    });
```

But the result is an exception with message: The expression cannot be evaluated.  A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate.

What am I doing wrong here?